# Graph Delta API for groups returning 400 "Resource not found for the segment 'contacts'."

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I develop an integration with Azure Ad which supports incremental synchronisations of users and groups.
It worked fine for quite a long time, but recently some (not all) of my customers started encountering one specific error.
For a request like:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$skiptoken=<TOKEN_FROM_PREVIOUS_SYNCRHONISATION>
```

The API returns a response with status code 400 and body:

```
   "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'contacts'.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "<SOME-REQUEST-ID>",
      "date": "2019-02-27T20:01:16"
    }
  }
```

I want to point out that this error occurs for some specific customers and I was not able to reproduce it on my environment.
Could someone give me a hint or two what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of days, my customers stopped raising the issue, so I believe the problem was temporary and on Azure side.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using skip tokens and delta tokens correctly.

You should only have a skip token when you get the next page of a delta response.

Later when you want to get changes, you have to use a delta token.
So $deltaToken instead of $skipToken.

Like the delta link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-events?view=graph-rest-1.0#sample-third-and-final-response

Comment: We are using the skip token and delta tokens correctly, we have a working integration with Azure Graph Delta v1 Queries for last one year. but the integration suddenly started failing a couple of days ago. Could you please elaborate on the error message itself? What does it signify?
I suspect there is a change in v1.0 API behavior, can you confirm that?

Comment: In that case it could just be a bug in MS Graph API. Raise a support ticket if you can / contact MS Graph folks on Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem when I send a request to the following endpoint

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$select=id,displayName,description&$expand=members
```

However, it works if I remove the "$expand=members" parameter from the URI. Could that be what's causing it in your case too?

Comment: My customers stopped raising the concern after couple of days, so I believe the problem was temporary